# How to make secure API calls using vanilla JS + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, rest, websecurity

Let me start off saying while I have been a developer for a while, I am brand new to PHP and fairly new to web development in general.

The site in question is vanilla JS frontend and PHP backend. I need to make a call to an external API with both sensitive user information + the site's API credentials.

I wasn't able to quickly find a simple solution to this [what seemed to me a] rather simple scenario explained in simple terms, so I stitched together what I gathered from several sources, and am doubting whether it is correct.

Here is an outline of my current solution, which works from a user perspective.

`request.js // contains user logic; makes api call to the site with [sensitive] user data`

```
await fetch('php_file_in_doc_root.php', user_data);
// do stuff with result
```

`php_file_in_doc_root.php // contains logic to make call to external api`

```
require_once(__DIR__ . "config_file_outside_doc_root.php");
$user_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
// make external api call with $credentials and $user_data 
echo $some_output
```

`config_file_outside_doc_root.php // contains site's credentials to external api`

```
$credentials = foo;
```

I'm wondering:

1. Is it safe (and why / why not) to store the api credentials outside doc root then require them in a php file inside the doc root?
2. When passing the sensitive user data from the frontend to the backend, is there anything I should do besides using HTTPS (which I am already doing).
3. Are there any gotchas I'm missing here or am I perhaps just completely misunderstanding how this should be done?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the same post. Also, at least the first question (about storing credentials outside the docroot) is well documented in tons of tutorials, even here on StackOverflow

Comment: TL;DR: yes, what you're doing sounds reasonable.